# How to create a counter like $index in AngularJS when you're not using ng-repeat?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

So I'm using the cocoon rails gem which uses jQuery to dynamically add form fields.

I have an angular model directive in a form field such as:

```
"ng-model" => "toy.kiteType[count]"
```

where count references $scope.count in the controller.  As I add new form field, I'd like to be able to reference each form field by its count index which means I need 0, 1, 2, etc. as I add form fields.  But each time I increment count, each form field only references the current value of count.

Is the way around this to have angular add in a count data attribute set to a specific number in the html form field?

Comment: I don't know for sure if this would work, but what happens if you do this:
Use ng-init on a parent element like this `ng-init="currentCount = count"` then change your ng-model to `"ng-model" => "toy.kiteType[count - currentCount--]"`. This may cause an off-by-one error depending on whether currentCount-- returns its value before or after decrementing 1.

Comment: But since every form field will have "toy.kiteType[count - currentCount--]" won't they all still be referencing the same point in the toy.kiteType array?

Comment: I don't think so, because each time `currentCount--` is referenced it decrements it by 1 each time. I haven't tested it though, that's why I haven't posted it as an answer. What happens if you try it with your code?
If it doesn't work, try writing ng-init like this (with curly braces) `ng-init="currentCount = count"`. That might work if the first approach doesn't.